Unable to connect to RabbitMQ bus after upgrading EasyNetQ to version 6.0.1 or later
I am having issues connecting to Rabbit after upgrading EasyNetQ to version 6.0.1 or later.
To ensure that there wasn't any other parts of the application creating these issues, I made a minimal project to test this, and I had the same issues there.
This is the entirety of my program:
using EasyNetQ;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System;

namespace MinimalRabbitProject
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "host=localhost;username=test;password=test";

            using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to RabbitMQ");
            }
        }
    }
}

This just seems to "fail silently". I get no errors/exceptions. However bus.Advanced.IsConnected is false, and I see no connection in RabbitMQ Management.
If I downgrade EasyNetQ to the previous version (5.6.0), this works fine, and I can see the connection in RabbitMQ Management.
I have tried upgrading to the latest version (7.8.0), but that doesn't work either. 5.6.0 is the last version that works.
From the release notes for version 6, I couldn't see anything that should affect creating a connection. My code is also the same as their sample code.
Using the RabbitMQ.Client library directly also works:
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
    UserName = "test",
    Password = "test",
    VirtualHost = "/",
    HostName = "localhost",
    Port = 5672
};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

Anybody got any tips about how I can get this working? If it matters, I am using RabbitMQ 3.12.12 and Erlang 25.3.2.8 locally. I have tried against a different server also, with same results (unsure about versions, but different than mine)

If using, try upgrading this nuget: "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" when using "EasyNetQ". I know that it sounds far fetch but I spent several hours trying to solve this mystery and ended up trying upgrading one nuget at a time. This "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" nuget did the trick!
Good luck!
